# Local processes of head node of a PBS cluster

Tags: ps, pbs

When I run `ps` or `top` on the head node of a PBS cluster, it shows all the processes running on all nodes.

I wonder if there is any way to limit to only the processes on the head node.

Comment: What version of PBS is this? I can tell you that Torque does not cause this behavior. My guess is that someone has aliased ps on that box.

Comment: I believe that `ps` and `top` are the original binaries. I was using Slurm previously and Slurm also does not have this behavior. Some clusters (eg OPNESSI) also has this clusterwise `ps` and `top` - http://openssi.org/cgi-bin/view?page=features.html. PBS Version: 4.2.4.1

Comment: It returns out that it is a "feature" of Scyld ClusterWare cluster. See http://gilgamesh.cheme.cmu.edu/scyld-doc/users-guide/batching.html has more

Comment: The answer to my original question `ps -ef | bpstat -P -1`.